# Question on productivity cycles

Tags: macroeconomics, productivity

What is “productivity cycles”? Is this different from business cycles?

And suggest papers on the productivity cycles as both theoretical and empirical studies?

I will be happy if you inform me productivity cycles, because I can’t get comprehansive information on that.